# Using multiple tables in Spring-Hibernate-Mysql web application

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am trying to use multiple tables in a web application which is based on Spring, Hibernate 5 and Mysql. How should I do that? Do I need multiple session factories and transaction managers?If no, how will the application differentiate between the two tables? 
Tables are connected through foreign key. Is there anything that I need to include because of the foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use annotations or xml configuration for it. make a search about mapping entities to tables in hibernate.
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="tbl_sky")
    public class Sky implements Serializable {
       ...
    }
```

Comment: So there is no need for separate transaction manager for second table?